# Remove stacked lines from edges

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Thats my graph: [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WgMpxN)

Green area should only have value `100`. Unfortunately, something weird happens. Why can I see green lines on edges?

[image: green lines on edges]

Answer (score 1):

In amcharts you have line colors and fill colors, in this chart they are both green, but if you set fill to green and line to black, you will remove the lines down.

```
...
        {
            "lineColor": "#000000",
            "type": "step",
            "id": "g2",
            "fillColors": "#00FF00",
            "fillAlphas": 1,
            "valueField": "visits2",
            "balloonText": "<div style='margin:5px; font-size:19px;'>Visits:<b>[[value]]</b></div>"
        }
...
```